# Drupal 7 : How to control Visibility of Main Menu based on selection of Menu Item in User_Menu?

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

I have Main_Menu which is my Primary and User_Menu which is my Secondary Links Menu. I want to show the Main_Menu when user clicks on one of the Menu Items in the User_Menu. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the use case for showing the primary menu after clicking on the secondary menu.  That seems to contradict the meanings of "primary" and "secondary". :)

But you might get some use out of the Menu Block module: http://drupal.org/project/menu_block